# Load balancing issue while connecting to IBM MQ using JMS + CCDT file

Tags: java, jms, load-balancing, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are trying to connect to IBMMQ using CCDT file and JMS configuration.
We are able to connect to it but we have an issue here:

since we are using spring to set connection factory with CCDT file, this is initialized once at the start of the application, but unfortunately it picks only one queue manager at a time,i.e it sends all the messages to same queue manager and it does not load balance.

Though i observed, if i manually set the CCDT file before every request then its able to load balance the Queue Managers, ideally it looks to me Queue Manager is decided whenever i set the URL to CCDT file. which is wrong practice. My expectation was to initialize the connection factory with CCDT file and then this configuration will be able to load balance on its own.

Can you help me this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  MQ does not load balance clients, it connection balances them.  The connection is the single most time consuming API call and in the case of a mutually authenticated TLS connection can take seconds to complete.  Therefore a good application design will attempt to connect once, then maintain that connection for the duration of the session.  The JMS architecture and Spring framework both expect this pattern.

The way that MQ provides load distribution (again, not true *balancing*, but rather round-robin *distribution*) is that the client connects a hop away from a clustered destination queue.  A message addressed to that clustered destination queue will round-robin among all the instances of that queue.

If it is a request-reply application, the thing listening for requests on these clustered queue instances addresses the reply message using the Reply-To QMgr and Reply-To Queue name from the requesting message.  In this scenario the requestors can fail over QMgr to QMgr if they lose their connection.  The systems of record listening on the clustered queues generally do not fail over across queue managers in order to ensure all queue instances are served and because of transaction recovery.

Short answer is that CCDT and MQ client in general are *not* where MQ load distribution occurs.  The client should make a connection and hold it as long as possible.  Client reconnect and CCDT are for *connection* balancing only.

Load distribution is a feature of the MQ cluster. It requires multiple instances of a clustered queue and these are normally a network hop away from the client app that puts the message.

Comment: Thanks Rob, appreciate your time and effort on this.Is their any other way I can think of load balancing to queuemanagers if i don't MQ cluster at infrastructure level? What i understand it can't be handled at client level(via java client library), still any thoughts of any alternative if i dnt have infrastructure to support cluster and needs to balance the load from client?

Comment: It's possible to use SDR/RCVR channels between the different QMgrs and using a dispatch application to intercept the messages and distribute them around if you wanted to re-invent something MQ already does extremely well. Just FYI, the requirement to balance messages *per client app* is extremely unusual. It is usually cheaper to spend the money on another MQ license or two than to configure MQ as if it were an HTTP server and then torture MQ into service under that design.